# Deploying a CNN: High training and test accuracy but low prediction accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Just starting out in ML and created my first CNN to detect the orientation of an image of a face. I got the training and testing accuracy up to around 96-99% over 2 different sets of 1000 pictures (128x128 RGB). However, when I go to predict an image from the test set on its own, the model rarely predicts correctly. I think there must be a difference in the way I load data into the model during testing vs prediction. Here is how I load the data into the model to train and test:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('twoThousandTransformed/', class_mode='categorical', batch_size=32, color_mode="rgb", target_size=(64,64))
val_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('validation/', class_mode='categorical', batch_size=32, color_mode="rgb", target_size=(64,64))
test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('test/', class_mode='categorical', batch_size=32, color_mode='rgb', target_size=(64,64))
```

And here is how I load an image to make a prediction:

```
image_path='inputPicture/02001.png'
image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(image_path)
input_arr = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
reshaped_image = np.resize(input_arr, (64,64,3))
input_arr = np.array([reshaped_image]) 
predictions = model.predict(input_arr)
print(predictions)
classes = np.argmax(predictions, axis = 1)
print(classes)
```

There must be some difference in the way the ImageDataGenerator handles the images vs. how I am doing it in the prediction. Can y'all help a noobie out? Thanks!

Edit: Below is my model

```
imageInput = Input(shape=(64,64,3))
conv1 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=16, activation='relu')(imageInput)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=12, activation='relu')(pool1)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(pool2)
pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
flat = Flatten()(pool3)
hidden1 = Dense(16, activation='relu')(flat)
hidden2 = Dense(16, activation='relu')(hidden1)
hidden3 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(hidden2)
output = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(hidden3)
model = Model(inputs=imageInput, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_it, steps_per_epoch=16, validation_data=val_it, validation_steps=8, epochs=25)
print('here we go!')
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_it)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to replicate the chosen image to resemble the batch size with which you trained the model. Also, because of such high training accuracy, it seems your model must be overfitting. So, try adding dropout or reducing the number of layers in your network, if the first thing doesn't work out.

Comment: How could I go about replicating the image? Also, about the over fitting thing: I could be understanding this wrong, but the 96-99% accuracy was on both the training set and test set (which are different sets of 1000 images) so I don't think over fitting occurred?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out how to replicate the image and make a batch of 32. The problem persists :(

Comment: Then, try working with your model and arriving at a good one.

Comment: Now I’m confused. My model seems to be really good at training and testing, but the prediction (using the same dataset) is very bad. How could that be a problem with the model? It must be a problem with the way I am predicting right?

Comment: But, as I have seen your preprocessing is the same in both case. I thought it would be a problem with maybe how you are batching it, that's why I told you to replicate a single test image to match batch size, but now that is also not the case.

Comment: Can you put up your model architecture here? So, maybe I could have a better idea.

Comment: Just added it. Thanks so much for taking a look at this!!

Comment: First thing is notice is you have not normalized the data kindly do: reshaped_image /= 255.

Comment: For training time, use ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255).

Comment: Another mistake, I see is that, you don't follow this: number of filters is directly proportional to layer number, you start with 128, then go down, start from 64, then go up. That should be the case normally. Use kernel sizes from this range [3, 5, 7]. Also, stay away from even kernels, they don't learn as better as odd kernels. Incorporate all this, then, let's see. And up vote the comments, if you find them helpful.

Comment: I did what you said, and it did make the model train faster and still get very high accuracy, but it still cannot make correct predictions.